# Serializing a custom class in ActiveRecord with specific syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization, rails-activerecord

I have a custom Interval class that I would like to use inside a few different ActiveRecord models. Currently I am storing the interval as a string with a specific syntax (w/ a custom validator to enforce formatting) and just creating a new object anytime I need to access Interval methods.

*What do I need to add to the ActiveRecord models/ Interval class to be able to use the interval as an object instead of a string, while still storing it in the database using the specific syntax?*

Hopefully that makes sense but if not hopefully the following example clears things up.

**The ActiveRecord class currently looks something like:**

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :interval, allow_blank: true, interval: true   # custom validator
  ...
```

**And to do anything useful I create a new interval:**

```
def some_helper
  ...
  interval_object = Interval.new(@my_class.interval)   # @my_class.interval is just a string with specific syntax
  if interval_object.useful?                           # 'useful' method
  ...
```

**But I would like to do:**

```
def some_helper
  ...
  if @my_class.interval.useful?   # 'useful' method
  ...
```

**Interval syntax that initialize expects:**

```
3:day  # represents every 3 days
1:week # represents every week
```

This seems like it should have a simple solution but I can't seem to find the right phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override the accessor and mutator methods to do what needs to be done:

```
def interval
  Interval.new(super)
end

def interval=(i)
  # Or whatever needs to be done to convert `i` back to a string,
  # keep in mind that `i` might be a string already.
  super(i.to_s)
end
```

Then you can say things like:

```
@my_class.interval.useful?
@my_class.interval = some_interval_object
@my_class.interval = some_string_that_looks_right
@my_class.update_attributes(:interval => some_interval_object)
@my_class.update_attributes(:interval => some_string_that_looks_right)
```

and The Right Things should happen.

Comment: Thanks, that got things working but now I have an additional question, I plan on using this class in multiple models. Would a connection adapter be the best way to abstract this out so I don't have to reimplement this in every model?

Comment: Do you mean "patch the connection adapter"? That might be pretty hairy. You might be able to get away with a fairly simple `has_interval_in :column_name` macro to generate the `column_name` and `column_name=` methods for you.